order nodes in plotly Sankey diagram
I am using go.Plotly trying to get the nodes to output in a certain order. I would like it to match the mapping_dict order, or at least keep the categories in the same order for each node.
I have looked at related questions, but their initial structure is different, so I don't think this is a repeat. Please let me know if not!
The goal is to go in A, B, C, D, E order (and, if one of those is missing, still keep the same order).
function call
fig = plot_sankey(links_dict, unique_source_targets, mapping_dict, colors=colors)

sample data
mapping_dict = {'B_round1': 0,
'C_round1': 1,
'D_round1': 2,
'E_round1': 3,
'A_round2': 4,
'B_round2': 5,
'C_round2': 6,
'D_round2': 7,
'E_round2': 8,
'A_round3': 9,
'B_round3': 10,
'C_round3': 11,
'D_round3': 12,
'E_round3': 13}
unique_source_targets=['B_round1',
'C_round1',
'D_round1',
'E_round1',
'A_round2',
'B_round2',
'C_round2',
'D_round2',
'E_round2',
'A_round3',
'B_round3',
'C_round3',
'D_round3',
'E_round3']
links_dict = {'source': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8], 'target': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], 'value': [1433, 2761, 521, 205, 117, 239, 472, 122, 61, 31, 282, 222, 81, 71, 77, 276, 59, 41, 60, 161, 2224, 6, 548, 2449, 371, 110, 36, 155, 482, 80, 34, 14, 105, 164, 52, 46, 30, 175, 47, 23, 37, 104]}
code
def plot_sankey(
links_dict,
unique_source_targets,
mapping_dict,
colors=None,
fig_title='Sankey Diagram',
subtitle=''):

# Generate formatted labels using a  compute_round_labels function, which produces the label name then (value, percentage)
formatted_labels = compute_round_labels(links_dict, unique_source_targets, mapping_dict)

# Convert the unique_source_target list into the formatted labels for display
display_labels = [formatted_labels[label] for label in unique_source_targets]

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Sankey(
            node=dict(
                pad=15,
                thickness=20,
                line=dict(color="black", width=0.5),
                label=display_labels,
                color=(colors if colors else "blue"),
            ),
            link=dict(
                source=links_dict["source"],
                target=links_dict["target"],
                value=links_dict["value"],
            ),
        )
    ]
)

# Setting the title with the subtitle using HTML formatting
full_title = f'{fig_title}<br><sub>{subtitle}</sub>'
fig.update_layout(title_text=full_title, font_size=20)

# Adjusting layout margin to accommodate title and subtitle
fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(t=100)  # Top margin; increase if title and subtitle are clipped
)

return fig

Edit: Adding the compute_labels function for context
 def compute_labels(links_dict, unique_source_targets, mapping_dict):
    category_totals = defaultdict(int)
    label_counts = defaultdict(int)

    # Accumulate values by source index for _round1 and _round2
    for source, value in zip(links_dict['source'], links_dict['value']):
        label = unique_source_targets[source]
        category_type = label.rsplit('_', 1)[1]  # Extracts the round type, e.g., 'round1'
        category_totals[category_type] += value
        label_counts[label] += value

    # Special handling for _round3 using the target indices
    for target, value in zip(links_dict['target'], links_dict['value']):
        # Check if target index corresponds to any label index in mapping_dict
        if target in mapping_dict.values():
            # Match the target index with its corresponding label
            label = next((label for label, index in mapping_dict.items() if index == target), None)
            if label and label.endswith('round3'):  # Ensure it's a round3 label
                category_type = label.rsplit('_', 1)[1]
                category_totals[category_type] += value
                label_counts[label] += value

    # Format the labels with values and percentages
    formatted_labels = {}
    for label, count in label_counts.items():
        category_type = label.rsplit('_', 1)[1]
        round_total = category_totals[category_type]
        percentage = int(round((count / round_total) * 100, 0))
        formatted_labels[label] = f"{label} ({count}, {percentage}%)"

    return formatted_labels


Bsically, you almost had it right. You must enforce a specific node order in a Sankey diagram so you need to make sure that the indices of your source and target nodes in your links_dict are consistent with the desired order of appearance as specified in your mapping_dict. Here is an approach. You'll need to add the values yourself
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

def plot_sankey(links_dict, unique_source_targets, mapping_dict, colors=None, fig_title='Sankey Diagram', subtitle=''):
    custom_order = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    sorted_items = sorted(mapping_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (x[0][-7:], custom_order.index(x[0][0])))
    mapping_dict = {item[0]: i for i, item in enumerate(sorted_items)}

    links_dict['source'] = [mapping_dict[unique_source_targets[x]] for x in links_dict['source']]
    links_dict['target'] = [mapping_dict[unique_source_targets[x]] for x in links_dict['target']]

    display_labels = [x.split('_')[0] + ' round' + x[-1] for x in unique_source_targets]  # Simplified label generation for example

    fig = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Sankey(
            node=dict(
                pad=15, thickness=20,
                line=dict(color="black", width=0.5),
                label=display_labels,
                color=colors if colors else ["blue"]*len(display_labels),
            ),
            link=dict(
                source=links_dict['source'],
                target=links_dict['target'],
                value=links_dict['value']
            )
        )
    ])

    full_title = f'{fig_title}<br><sub>{subtitle}</sub>'
    fig.update_layout(title_text=full_title, font_size=20)
    fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=100))

    return fig

mapping_dict = {'B_round1': 0, 'C_round1': 1, 'D_round1': 2, 'E_round1': 3, 'A_round2': 4, 'B_round2': 5, 
                'C_round2': 6, 'D_round2': 7, 'E_round2': 8, 'A_round3': 9, 'B_round3': 10, 'C_round3': 11, 
                'D_round3': 12, 'E_round3': 13}
unique_source_targets = list(mapping_dict.keys())
links_dict = {
    'source': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8],
    'target': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
    'value': [1433, 2761, 521, 205, 117, 239, 472, 122, 61, 31, 282, 222, 81, 71, 77, 276, 59, 41, 60, 161, 2224, 6, 548, 2449, 371, 110, 36, 155, 482, 80, 34, 14, 105, 164, 52, 46, 30, 175, 47, 23, 37, 104]
}

fig = plot_sankey(links_dict, unique_source_targets, mapping_dict, colors=['red', 'blue']*7)
fig.show()




Thanks so much for the info, very helpful! So looks like I need to write a function to reorder mapping_dict (keys will be an aribtrary number of characters; 'A', 'B' were just examples) and then use it to reorder links_dict. I'm alllllmost following what your code above does. Would the function  to reorder mapping_dict and links_dict need to happen before compute_labels (added above)?
